After updating from 23.10 to 24.04 LTS I have to reset secure boot to load into ubuntu
After updating to 24.04 LTS I have been getting constant issues but mostly:
Could not create MokListRT: Volume full

Could not create MokListXRT: Volume full

Could not create SbatlevelRT: Volume Full

Could not create MokListTrustedRT: Volume full

Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed: Volume Full
To even load grub i have to reset dbx signiature keys under secure boot which seem to be taking up the entirety of the nvram. After resetting the key to default it loads grub and will proceed to ubuntu.
I have windows 11 installed on a separate drive and if i boot into it directly through the bios it will load normally however under msinfo32 the PCR7 Configuration shows as "Binding not possible". Normally and also after resetting the key it shows as "Bound". If i reset the key but dont boot into ubuntu then grub will work fine, letting me boot into windows or bios as normal only when i boot into ubuntu and power cycle it then it will show the previous issue. I also have tried disabling secure boot but it has not helped. I remember i had the same error message on 22.04 LTS but after booting into windows once through bios it kind of just went away and i forgot about it.
Another (minor) issue is that my gpu (gtx 1050 ti) will just not function properly using nvidia drivers, and instead ubuntu will use software rendering. Using the open scource drivers allows the gpu to be utilised but the drivers have lower performance so if possible i would like to stay on the nVidia drivers but this is a much less important issue as i have a dedicated windows install for gaming so i would not really be devastated to not have a fix for this as this is mostly just quality of life.
Any help mould be very much appreciated. My specifications are: i7-7700k, GTX 1050 Ti, ASUS H110M-R on the latest bios, 1tb wd hdd (ubuntu), 2tb samsung sata ssd (windows 11).
I have found a link which desrcibes the boot issue almost exactly but on their system dbx signiature is forbidden signiature and i dont use bitlocker on my windows install. Link
Thanks for any help
EDIT: another issue has appeared that if i suspend the pc and try to wake it up again then the display wont come back and i have to force shut down to get display back
EDIT2: gpu driver issue has just dissapeared. Not sure why

Why did you upgrade to 24.10?  24.10 is a development release and NOT a stable supported release, nor is it the LTS release. 24.04 LTS is the currently supported release.

I meant 24.04 sorry I misspelled thanks

The bootloader is screwed or has not been updated to reflect the disk partitioning to operating system mapping.

How would I go about fixing this? Or do I have to reinstall?

After resetting the keys then it runs fine and shows fine in bios and grub will work as usual. Only after loading ubuntu and then power cycling it then will grub fail to load and the dbx key is taking up the entirety of my mobo nvram as far as i can tell
